# Implement smooth component transition animation when route change

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-component-router

how to implement smooth component transition animation when route change in Angular2 RC-1 ?

I am using angular component router (not the deprecated one).

I am fairly new to angular2 and typescript. Have some experience in Angular1.x

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any support for this yet. You can implement a custom router-outlet that does that.